# How do I remove this Electrolux drum paddle?

Tags: washing-machine, washer

I have a Simpson SWF-1076 (now owned by Electrolux). The paddles look exactly like this [Electrolux part no. 50249701009](https://www.espares.co.uk/product/es563845/washing-machine-drum-paddle), though I can't be sure it's the same underneath.

How do I remove this design of paddle?

[image]
[image]

I can't find instructions online, and I can't see what's inside the holes. Pulling and sliding has not worked. I really hope it's not screwed on from the outside of the drum, as then I'll have to take apart the whole machine....

**Update**

Thanks for the advise gentlemen but the reality is that you will have to take the machine apart. I have tried all possible solutions and at the end of the day, the machine had to be taken apart. No other way!

Comment: Have you tried taking the top off the machine to see? You can rotate the drum and see. No need to disassemble the entire dryer.

Comment: Thanks @JeffCates. I took the top off and had a look at the outer drum, the only access into it is the filling hose.  I took the hose off and could see a row of closely spaced bolts on the outside of the inner drum. But they are too far back to be related to the paddles. I did find one article online which said sometimes the paddles are unscrewed through the opening for the filling hose. But sadly not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Getting To The Retaining Screw(s) Of The Paddle

**REMOVE ALL POWER FROM THE MACHINE. UNPLUG FROM ELECTRICAL SOURCE.**

The sump hose is the thick hose that will run from the very bottom of the drum to the the pump.

You need to take this hose off to gain access, again, make sure you have removed all power from the machine as you could go near power carrying components.

Once the sump hose is off you can see the drum paddle retaining screw through the hole. Pull the washing machine out and tip it back so that it rests at about a 45˚ or so angle. Makes sure the washing machine is secure and cannot move so that it is safe to work on from underneath or, get someone to hold it for you so it doesn't tip over onto your head or hands.

Now you can access from below in most washing machines, especially the cheaper ones as it costs too much to put a base on the machine.

The sump hose may be sealed into place so you might need some sealant such as silicone sealant to reseal the hose once you are finished replacing the paddle.

Once that hose is off you should be able to see inside and see the retaining screw, bear in mind that these will often be Torx type screws. Undo that and the paddle should be able to be pushed forward or back depending on the fitting in that particular washing machine model, and the drum paddle should just pop off. Unless it's one of the really hard ones.

The rear screw, if you have one, you have to take off the top breather hose at the top of the washing machine's outer drum.

Obviously you will need to rotate the drum to access the second screw if it has 2 screws.

To refit the new drum paddle which you have, simply do the process in reverse.

Your image shows 1 screw, but the paddle looks like it may use 2. Until you take the paddle off, you may not know for sure.

Also it seems that there are part numbers manufactured into the top of some paddles. If so, it would be close to the holes in the front part of the paddle.

If you can find the part numbers, you might be able to find the actual part online for an image then determine how many screws are in it. It could be easier than this and just be one screw holding it on from the top...where is a good guess as it could be any number of the holes.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, by removing the drain hose I was able to see the outside of the inner drum, including a hole that lined up with one of the cylindrical holes in the underside of the paddle (visible above). But there was no screw in the hole. So while I'm sure your answer works often, sadly not in this case..:-( I'm not sure what you mean by a top breather hose - there is only an inlet hose that I can see. So while this is a great answer, I'm reluctant to accept it straight away in the hope that someone else can give an answer that's correct in my situation.

Comment: There should be a hose on top to allow air to enter the tub. You might also remove the water inlet hose and see if you can find the screws. If you can't see any then they are screwed from the inside of the drum, or not user serviceable. It could also be possible that the screws have fallen out, if you see where they should have been. Could this be why you are looking to replace them?